# Wordpress multisite, serving a simple html site

Tags: wordpress

I've got a webserver managed by Ajenti.
I'm currently hosting a wordpress multisite on test.com for example

I've set it up as follows:

- test.com
- test.com/2014
- test.com/2015
- test.com/2016 (I want this to be a simple html/js site i.e. not wordpress)

How do I achieve this?

- Can I do it from Ajenti?
- Can I setup wordress multisite to serve the sub-site from a folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the folder "2016" using the Ajenti file manager then simply link to it, but without the use of any PHP, the Wordpress panel won't allow you to change/manage anything in that folder. It will have to be edited manually.

Comment: Sorry, how exactly do you do this? Ajenti is already serving the multisite from /srv/test.com/